# How to identify an entry and lookup column that does not match a master table for quick reference

Tags: python, sql, pandas, match

I have three tables across two different databases. The master table is on one and the other two are on another. I want to be able to check the two tables against the master table across 8 total columns (4 from each table) and find the entry and lookup column to see where they do not match. I have read the data in, sliced and left merged the data but now I am stuck on how to code in the actual "looking for non-matching" entries. Here are two examples of the merged columns from the master (df3) and the one I am looking for non matching (df2)

```
merged_rmga = pd.merge(slice_df3_retailmga, slice_df2_retailmga, how="left", on = "RMF", indicator = True)
    merged_advrcorp = pd.merge(slice_df3_advcorp, slice_df2_advcorp, how="left", on = "AC", indicator = True)
```

Any help would be great! Thanks